# Why javac can compile in this case

Tags: java, javac

My environment is Windows 7 and JDK 1.7.

I have *not* set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable; `echo %CLASSPATH%` outputs nothing.

Java compiler: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin`
Java source: is in `D:\tmpmulu\Tj.java`

I run the command like below:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\javac.exe" -cp d:\tmpmulu\ d:\tmpmulu\Tj.java
```

It works. The command set the classpath and compiled the file.

But when I change the command to use `.` instead of `d:\tmpmulu\` as my classpath:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\javac.exe" -cp . d:\tmpmulu\Tj.java
```

It's also OK.

That confused me. The `.` means the current path, it should be `c:\`. How did it run successfully?

Another question is command like below:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\javac.exe" -cp d:\tmpmulu\ Tj.java
```

As my thinking, the classpath is set to `d:\tmpmulu\`, it should find the `Tj.java` file. But the result is 'file not found Tj.java'.

Can anyone tell me details?

Comment: I've voted for this to be migrated to http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, presumably your code doesn't rely on having anything in the classpath, basically. If it *only* uses classes from the JDK, that's absolutely fine.

Note that the classpath is only used to find *class files* - not *source code*. That explains both the *lack* of failure when your source path isn't on the classpath, and then failure when you try to use the classpath to locate `Tj.java`.

Comment: Oh, I understand. In this case, there is no need to specify the classpath. So whatever what classpath I set, it didn't affect the compiling.

Comment: @roast_soul No, anything used by the class being compiled must be on the classpath--it can't be arbitrary.

Comment: @Dave Newton But I use a non-existed path as classpath, it still compiled ok.As below command:     C:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\javac.exe" -cp c:\nosuchpath\ d:\tmpm
ulu\Tj.java

Comment: @roast_soul: Suppose you want to use Joda Time - a library, which you only have a jar file for. *That* has to be in your classpath, because the compiler needs to know what classes exist in `org.joda.time.*` etc. If you *only* refer to classes within the JDK, that's fine - `javac` already knows about those.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're compiling  with **javac -cp . myClass.java**, you can omit it the -cp . completely, since it's the default classpath.
Second, **-cp** should be used when you need to specify references to additional JARs file not included in the standard JDK library, such as a jdbc connector. If your class doesn't require any additional library, then it doesn't really matter what directory you tell **javac** to look into.

Comment: `.` being on the default classpath is version-dependent.